# Cannot horizontally center fixed width div in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am creating a template for a website.

The example is at [Framework Login Page](http://test.webspirited.com/framework/login)
The main CSS sheet is at: [master.css](http://test.webspirited.com/framework/application/assets/css/master.css)

I am trying to center the main parent div.

I am using

```
#body {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('pathtoimage.png');
}

#inner_body{
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="inner_body"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a (very) old IE bug.

Fortunately, it's been fixed since IE 6, but you do need to have a proper doctype on your page to cause IE to use "standards" rendering mode and respect your `margin: auto` style.  On a page without a doctype, IE instead uses "quirks" mode, which falls back to old, non-standard behavior.

Quirksmode has a good [page on doctypes and standards mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) that explains why you want to make sure your pages have a correct doctype, including some nice tables spelling out what each browser will do differently in quirks and standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS for your "body" div to include:

```
text-align: center;
```

And remove any text-aligns you may have on the "inner_body" div, it should inherit from body.

Comment: Or, if you're just targeting even halfway-recent versions of IE, the original posted styles will work if you just add a proper doctype to your page.

Comment: @zerocrates: can you please post your comment (maybe with a reason why the doctype matters) as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation why you should use the correct doctype.

1. Use the correct DOCTYPE ( Document Type Definition, or
   DTD)

This defines which version of HTML or XHTML your document
is actually using. It's needed by browsers or other tools
to process the document correctly.

Using an incomplete, outdated or no DOCTYPE at all, throws
some browsers into “Quirks” mode, where the browser assumes
you’ve written old-fashioned, invalid markup.

This means that your web pages may not render well in all
the major browsers.